# Why isn't sql server using all of the available memory

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012, ssrs

I Have SQL server 2012 standard 64bit with 64GB RAM and 40 CPU cores. In the server properties, I can see that all the RAM is listed in the memory field on the general tab. Underneath the Memory tab, I have set the minimum to 50,000 MB and the maximum is still the default value.

Both RAMMap and Task Manager show MSSQL using 27GB and having 37GB available.

What's the deal? Why isn't sqlserver and reporting server using all of the RAM when I run a large report?

Comment: How big are your databases?

Comment: Right now about 10 total. Going to add another 5gb database in march.

Comment: Three comments: The first is that your databases fit entirely in memory and they don't take up much, only 10GB which is why not much memory is being used. The second is that Min Server Memory only governs what the minimum amount of memory SQL Server will use when there is memory pressure or working set trimming. The third is that SQL Server doesn't ramp up memory usage, it uses it as it needs it - SQL Server doesn't reserve memory like what you're expecting. Upon startup it doesn't allocate the min server memory, that's only used when freeing memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that your queries aren't large enough to fill the memory. This is a good thing, unless you are seeing heavy I/O while running the report.

Answer (score 2):

You said in a comment above that your databases are only about 10GB total.  SQL Server can easily load them entirely in memory, including data, indexes, and temporary data from your queries.  This is a good thing, and provides better performance than reading from disk.